# How to use path class?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.nio.file.Path p = Paths.get("E:/test/Hellow.txt");

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(p.getParent() + "hellow2.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hi, How to use path class?

I want input file `E:/test/Hellow.txt` to be output to `E:/test/Hellow2.txt`

But I'm getting `E:\testHellow2.txt` as the output file name. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: save "E:/testHellow2.txt" but i want "E:/test/Hellow2.txt"

Comment: `p.getParent() + "hellow2.txt"`: you could include a `/` between the directory and the file name. That is `p.getParent() + "/hellow2.txt".

Comment: In my opinion this is one of the reasons why `Path` exists. Concatenation path component strings and forgetting to put a slash in between. `Path` does this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `resolve` the parent directory of the source file with the new file name the copy should get.

Have a look at this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide the source file (must exist, won't check for that here)
    Path sourceFile = Paths.get("D:/ZZ--temp/Hellow.txt");
    // then try to copy source to target
    try {
        Path copy = Files.copy(sourceFile,
                /* get the parent directory of the source file 
                 * and resolve it with the file name of the copy
                 */
                sourceFile.getParent().resolve("Hellow2.txt"),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        if (Files.exists(copy)) {
            System.out.println("Successfully copied"
                    + sourceFile.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                    + " to "
                    + copy.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It really copies the file and outputs the following on my machine (paths not equal to yours!)

```
Successfully copiedD:\ZZ--temp\Hellow.txt to D:\ZZ--temp\Hellow2.txt
```